# Block triangularisation of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, triangularization

So there is a question that the professor that i don't really understand

I was asked to give the change of basis matrix U and its inverse $U^{-1}$ so that $U^{-1}AU$ is in block triangular form (the original language of the question is not English, so I hope these are the right terms)

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}-5&-4&5\\3&3&-4\\-6&-5&5\end{bmatrix}$$

So the characteristic polynomial would be

$$det(Xid_3-A)=(x-4)(1+x+x^2)$$

Since the characteristic polynomial of A can not be factored in $\Bbb R$, A cannot be triangulated. Now we can find a basis B where the matrix induced by A is block triangular sable.

Let $v=(0,0,1)$ then $(A-4id_V)v=\begin{bmatrix}-9&-4&5\\3&-1&-4\\-6&-5&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}5\\-4\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Define $u:=(A-4id_v)v=\begin{bmatrix}5\\-4\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $w:=Au=\begin{bmatrix}-4\\-1\\-5\end{bmatrix}$

The vectors $u,v,w$ build a basis in $\Bbb R^3$ because they are linearly independent. In the basis, $B=(w,u,v)$ the representation matrix $L_A$ would be block triangular.

$$(A^2+A+id_3)(A-4id_3)v=0 \rightarrow A Au+Au+u=0 \rightarrow Aw=-w-u$$

Then $$_bM_b(L_A)=\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&0\\-1&0&1\\0&0&4\end{bmatrix}$$

And then it goes on to determine $U,U^{-1}$

My question is, what the hell is all this? Which part of linear algebra is this? I tried to find videos or other online resources where the steps are explained but I couldn't find anything.

What does this do?

EDIT: There is a similar exercise with solutions, maybe helpful in recognising what this is:

$$D=\begin{bmatrix}2&-2&3&3&-3\\0&-2&3&3&-3\\-1&-1&1&2&-3\\0&0&0 &-2&3\\0&0&0&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Determine the similar matrix in block triangular form
[image]

where $D_i, 1\le i \le r$ are the companion matrices of an irreducible factor of the characteristic vectors.

[image]

[image]

We then choose a vector, that does not vanish when multiplied by (D − id5)(D2 + 2id5). We
choose
[image]
[image]

Comment: This kind of question seems unconventional. Block triangularization is something that is usually done via a more specific technique. For example, one might use the [real Jordan form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices), [Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition), or [Frobenius normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form).

Comment: @BenGrossmann well I would love to know what it is...I was told by someone its some sort of algorithm but nobody knows the name of the algorithm

Comment: Is there a textbook that the professor is using? Perhaps the textbook gives a name for the algorithm, even if this name is not in English

Comment: she isnt using any text book....teaching is insanely bad...We use a script but its not in the script. she explained it once during the lectures which i didnt go because of corona (they require a covid certificate) normally they would live zoom it but i dont usually watch it because she sucks at explaining things. Every youtube video does a bbetter job....But i seem to have missed an important one

Comment: Perhaps you should ask one of your classmates, or ask the teaching assistant if there is one. In the meantime, we might be able to answer your question of "what does this do", but I am not quite sure what you mean with this question.

Comment: I added another example with solutions...I mean i can follow the steps and do the same thing if im given another similar question in the exam...But i really dont understand what the purpose is behind this..I guess thats what im asking..

Comment: Do you know what "diagonalizing" a transformation refers to? Do you know about Jordan canonical form?

Comment: If you're familiar with either of those, the usage of this triangularization is similar

Comment: I do understand both diagonalising and jordan form...What i dont understand is why in the solutions they randomly pick a standard basis and multiplying it with $D$ and call it the second vector and so on...Is this all just a neat way to avoid $\Bbb R$ restraints? If we can do the whole thing in complex plane i could actually solve it easily. Is this just a neat way to avoid complex solutions of a polynomial?

Comment: Yes. In a nutshell, the whole thing is a version of Jordan form that avoids any complex numbers